# Intent error can not receive value from another activity then force close

Tags: android, android-intent

Can anyone help, my program force closed, was it a nullpointer error or something, because it cannot get values from another class. Can anyone tell me where did I go wrong ?

This the the giver

```
if(position == 0){

  Intent i = new Intent(ListKategoriKUHAP.this, PasalbyKatUndangKUHAP.class);
  i.putExtra("value1", "1");
     startActivity(i);

}
else
{
if(position == 1){

     Intent i = new Intent(ListKategoriKUHAP.this, PasalbyKatUndangKUHAP.class);
     i.putExtra("value1", "2");
     startActivity(i);

 }
```

And this is the receiver

```
private void setData()
{
     Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        String value = extras.getString("value1");
    if(value=="1")
        {
            listKamus = dbHelper.getAllPasalBab1();
        }
     }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, listKamus);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

There's no problem with getAllPasalBab1() I've already tried modifying the code, but when I use intent it's gives a error null pointer. Can somebody help me?

Here's the logcat

```
02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750): Process: com.example.KUHP_KUHAP_KUHperdata, PID: 1750

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.KUHP_KUHAP_KUHperdata/com.example.KUHP_KUHAP_KUHperdata.PasalbyKatUndangKUHAP}: java.lang.NullPointerException

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:480)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at com.example.KUHP_KUHAP_KUHperdata.PasalbyKatUndangKUHAP.setData(PasalbyKatUndangKUHAP.java:215)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at com.example.KUHP_KUHAP_KUHperdata.PasalbyKatUndangKUHAP.onCreate(PasalbyKatUndangKUHAP.java:34)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)

02-27 20:20:28.460: E/AndroidRuntime(1750):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: can you add the logcat error part as well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this will help, but your List `listkamus` is getting null. Try comparing `value` by using `equals(String)` method and try this little correction:

Make `listkamus` as your class variable, and then,

```
private void setData()
{
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    if (mIntent != null) 
    {
        String value = mIntent.getStringExtra("value1");
        if(value.equals("1"))
        {
            listKamus = dbHelper.getAllPasalBab1();
        }
     }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Data>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, listKamus);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: It's working good !!!! all thnx for the equals example !!! really, great help thnx !!!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably `listKamus` is `null` when extras equals to null or `value` not equals to `1` because you are not initializing  `listKamus` if if condition fail so either set adapter inside inner if block or initializing `listKamus` before passing to adapter as:

```
  // initialize listKamus here
listKamus=.....;
if (extras != null) 
{
    String value = extras.getString("value1");
if(value=="1")
    {
        listKamus = dbHelper.getAllPasalBab1();
         // or set ListView Adapter here
     }
 }
```

or also use `equals` instead of `==` for comparing String values.

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with listkamus, listkamus work just fine.

Comment: @user2977799 : as in log `NullPointerException ArrayAdapter.getCount` means means data source is null

Comment: I don't know how to use equals !!! i thought this how i used it "(value equals "1")", then the guy below show the way, wow thnx for saying use equals user2977799 !!! it's work now after i use equal !!! Really2 thnx there !!!

Comment: @user2977799 : see my answer i told you before 44 mins `or also use equals instead of == for comparing String values.`